# Pass data between two non related lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have two non-related lightning components within a lightning service console. Not within an App nor within a hierarchy. Is it possible pass data between these two components?

Comment: Have you tried application events?

Comment: Yes I did. No luck yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pass values using workspaceAPI opentab() method with pageReference. Following article explains more:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_open_pagereference.htm

Answer (score 0):

I used session/localStorage to achieve that. Unfortunately Aura Events wouldn't be useful because they're not on the same hierarchy.